# Coinbase sent FTM tokens back to Wealthsimple sending address mentioned on Etherscan

Tags: blockchain

Few days back i moved my FTM crypto to other exchange but on ERC-20 network which was not supported by recipient. So I raised a ticket and Coinbase sent my FTM crypto back to wealthsimple sending address. But I see my FTM tokens in wealthsimple centralize exchange address and its not reflecting in my account. I have provided both the transaction hash to Wealthsimple to transfer token to my account. I want to know that will wealthsimple transfer my tokens to my wallet ?